# When does the minimum distance to the boundary exist?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, euclidean-geometry

Let $(S,d)$ be the metric space, where $$S=\{s=[1/s_1,1/s_2]\in \mathbb{R}_{++}^2: s_1+s_2\leq1\}$$ and $d$ is the Euclidean distance metric. $\mathbb{R}_{++}^2$ here suggests that the vector is strictly positive in all its elements. Consider a set $C \subset S$ such that $C=\{c=[1/c_1,1/c_2]\in \mathbb{R}_{++}^2: c_1+c_2<1\}.$ We know that the set of boundary points of $C$ in $(S,d)$ is $\partial C = \{c=[1/c_1,1/c_2]\in \mathbb{R}_{++}^2: c_1+c_2=1\},$ and my question is that can we conclude that for every $c'\in C,$ there is $c''\in \partial C$ such that $$c'' = argmin_{c''\in \partial C} d(c',c'')?$$
As shown in the plot below, all $c'' \in \partial C$ are on the black convex curve, and all $c' \in C$ are above the convex curve. Hence, graphically, I think the above statement is correct. However, I'm wondering if there is a rigorous proof that does not involve calculating the first- and second-order derivatives?

[image]

Comment: What order do you place on $\partial C$ for $\text{argmin}_{c''\in \partial C} d(c', c'')$ to make sense?

Comment: @Jakobian I'm sorry, but I don't quite understand what you mean by "order on $\partial C$" here. To rephrase my question, can we prove that there exists a minimum $d(c',c'')$ given the setup above?

Comment: You're calculating the minimal argument over elements of $\partial C$, what does that mean?

Comment: @Jakobian Thanks for the reply. What I meant is that: I am trying to prove, for every element in $c' \in C$, if there is an element in its set of boundary points (i.e., $c'' \in \partial C$) that minimizes $d(c',c''),$ where $d$ is the Euclidean distance metric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\partial C$ is a non-empty closed subspace of the plane, taking $c'\in C$, there exists a closed ball $D = D(c', r)$ such that $D\cap \partial C$ is a non-empty compact set. So the function  $c''\mapsto d(c', c'')$ defined on $D\cap \partial C$ must achieve a minimum. That is, there is some $c'' = c_0\in \partial C\cap D$ which minimizes $d(c', c'')$. But for $c''\in \partial C\setminus D$ we have $d(c', c'') > r \geq d(c', c_0)$, so it minimizes the distance on the whole of $\partial C$.

As to why $\partial C$ is closed. Suppose that $(x_n, y_n)\to (x, y)$ where $1/x_n+1/y_n= 1$ and $x_n, y_n>0$. If it were $x = 0$, then $1/x_n \to \infty$, but $1/x_n \leq 1/x_n +1/y_n = 1$, so that's impossible. Similarly, we can't have $y = 0$. Then $\lim_{n\to\infty} (1/x_n + 1/y_n) = 1/x+1/y = 1$ so that $(x, y)\in\partial C$.

Comment: Thank you so much! Just a few questions for clarification: 1) It is not clear to me why $\partial C$ is a closed subspace of the plane. My understanding is that $\partial C$ is closed if any sequence $\{c_n\}$ in $\partial C$ converges in norm to a $c^* \in \partial C.$ However, if we consider $\{c_n\} = \{1/n,(n-1)/n\},$ it does not converge to any elements in $\partial C$, right?  2) From the third line, did you mean "there is some $c'' = c_0\in \partial C\cap D$ which minimizes $d(c', c'')$. But for any other $c''\in \partial C\setminus D$ we have $d(c', c'') > r \geq d(c', c_0)$"?

Comment: @xuan 1) The problem is that $(c_n)_n$ doesn't converge in $\mathbb{R}^2$. 2) Yes, exactly. I'll edit it

Comment: Thank you so much!! That's very helpful!